# How to decrease load times in azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, web-hosting

I have deployed a nodejs app on azure app service (B2 plan). Whenever I try to access the app in a new device or incognito mode, it takes around 30 seconds to load the app's home page. Accessing the app in the same browser after closing it has no issues (probably because it's caching).

I have deployed the same app on vercel and it loads instantly on any device, so the problem lies in Azure.

Anything that I can do to improve load times in Azure (I kinda need to deploy my app on azure only)?

I tried turning on the always on feature of azure but it has no effect on the load times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slow repsonse time in app services can be a result of many things. However, I got some tips for you that you could benefit from.

1. If you got a lot of content on your website or if you are hosting a fat client, make use of [Azure CDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cdn/). It is not too expensive.
2. If your application would be totally stateless, that is, not managing any user authentication, turn off the ARR Affinity setting in the platform settings. This speeds up the load balancing
3. If the media on your website is large, try scaling them down to reduce the load time as well. Use the built in network watcher in your browser to find out whats taking so long :)

Best of luck!